# How to differentiate application code from system code in dalvik

Tags: android, dalvik

In android dalvik, at every function call site, I want to check whether the caller is application code and the callee is system code.

I know a way to do this from an article： *Vetting Undesirable Behaviors in Android Apps with Permission Use Analysis*

in the end of chapter 3.1.1.

> Fortunately, we find an efficient way to differentiate application code from system code by checking their class loader, because system code is loaded by a distinct class loader in Dalvik to ensure the VM integrity”

I add this in the dalvik code *dalvik/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp:*

> ALOGD("ClassLoader:%s", methodToCall->clazz->classLoader->clazz->descriptor);

but the result is always :

> ClassLoader:Ldalvik/system/PathClassLoader;

It seems that the classloaders are the same. Is there something I did wrong?

Any suggestions or resources I can learn from are welcome!

Comment: You're printing the name of the classloader's class. There's nothing that prevents the system and apps from using different instances of the same class loader class. Walk up the stack trace and print the class loader reference and method name at each frame.

Comment: Here's an old stack walker from the "gingerbread" days, used to assess permissions... might be instructive. (The security code was later removed.) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread-release/vm/native/java_security_AccessController.c , some bits in InternalNative.c.